# How to get the Job Instance of Long Running Jobs in Quartz?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have created my own job class by extending the default class added couple of member variables and member methods. I saw the job gets triggered and is running for a very long time.

I just wanted to get the Job Instance not the JobDetail and wanted to invoke any member methods which has been defined by me or wanted to access the member variables.

Could you please let me know how we can achieve this?

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not such way, probably because quartz is meant to be compatible with a remote scheduling mode (i.e. cluster).

But if you are using it in a single server / application context, you could probably implement your own JobFactory (http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/simpl/SimpleJobFactory.html) that will just delegate to the super class the creation of the instance, and then register the instance somehow in a map or something else. Then you'll have to loop over the map keys to find the instance you are looking at.

Be careful of memory leaks with such a solution

---

### Quick example:

In your spring configuration file:

```
<!-- quartz scheduler -->
<bean id="orchestration-api-quartz-factory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:spring/quartz.properties"/>
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="service.scheduler.SpringServiceJobFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the basic implementation of your Factory:

```
/**
 * This job factory tries to locate the spring bean corresponding to the JobClass.
 *
 * @author Mathieu POUSSE
 */
public class SpringServiceJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements JobFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) 
                                       throws Exception {
        // create or get the bean instance
        Object bean = this.context.getBean(bundle.getJobDetail().getJobClass());

        // do what you want with the bean
        // but remeber what you did, otherwise if you forget to forget
        // you will have memory leaks !!!

        // myConcurrentMap.put("job.key", bean);

        return bean ;
    }

}
```

HIH

Comment: Can you please explain in detail with an example? This would be of a great help, as I am looking to achieve exactly same. Also, is this possible with any other third party library with their standard setting (i.e. no custom implementation of any API)?

Comment: Thanks ZNK-M. I am not using Spring, so in that case I should extend org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory and override newJob()? Also, I am spawning a thread from execute() method and I have to check the thread's status, so do you mean I should put the thread instance in myConcurrentMap? And where this map should be declared? In execute() or outside execute()?

Comment: Well, I think you should ask your question in a separate thread because it seems quite different... I don't understand why you are creating new threads. It is quartz that is responsible of that. You just have to crate a new class has shown, declare it in the quartz config (`org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = MyJobFactory`) and this service has a concurrent map that keeps track of all the running instances. This way you can do something like `MyJobFactory.instances.get("the-job-key")` to retrieve a running instance.

Comment: I have already put the question, but didn't get any response there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961381/a-handle-to-quartz-job

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm talking to an empty room :) but I am programmatically creating jobs and assigning a central trigger handler on application startup. It appears (so far) that Quartz will simply hand you the existing job when you use the factory to "Create". I'm not seeing any new records in the Quartz tables for either job nor trigger.