# Access Quartz Job object while running

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

In my java application, I have a Quartz job that runs once a day that handles a certain task. Inside my `execute` method is just this:

```
int maxRetry = 10;
while(retryCnt < maxRetry) {
    try {
      doLogic();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      retryCnt++;
    }
}
```

`retryCnt` is an instance variable.

I'm building a monitoring screen for this Job and one of the things I'd like to display to the user is the `retryCnt` value. Is it possible to retrieve the Job object (when it's running) so I can get the `retryCnt` value? If the job is not running, then I get no Job object and a 0 retry count.

My screen does not refresh real time, but with the help of a Refresh button. I plan to place the running-job-class-retrieving logic in its actionlistener.

If what I'm explaining is not possible, can someone suggest an approach for me to achieve my expected behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Job Instance of Long Running Jobs in Quartz?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620024/how-to-get-the-job-instance-of-long-running-jobs-in-quartz)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you would be interested in looking at the JObListener that gives you a real time Job Object